# Can I make a monster indestructible?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Let's say I have a monster on the field. This is my best card, and I want to make it untouchable by anything.

An example would be a monster who's effect can't be negated, and is not affected by card effects, equipped with an equip card that means it cannot be destroyed by battle, and that card cannot be destroyed either.

Are there any scenarios that allow this possibility?

> Indestructible: Cannot be removed from the field by any means.

Comment: Does this card belong to a specific archetype? Or is it more like how to make untouchable *any* card.

Comment: @DarkCygnus To all. I play against many archetypes including Cyber Dragons and Lightsworns

Comment: I see, and is this "best card" you have a specific one (name?)

Comment: @DarkCygnus nope. My necessary to think of one, but probably Divine Dragon Knight Felegrand

Comment: Do you have discord?

Comment: We can discuss in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49/board-and-card-games) if you like :)

Comment: Other effects you may want to be aware of: Opponent taking control over your Monster/tributing it/using it as Fusion/Synchro/XYZ material. The last 3 options are not even card effects. And if your Monster "cannot be used as XYZ material" they will come up with a new monster type, just like "cannot be used as Synchro material" became less a bother when XYZ came out.

Comment: For what definition of destroyed? The game's definition or "anything that will make you lose the monster as currently on the field"? The latter would include all of, but not just the following: return to your hand, loss of control to your opponent, any 'send to the graveyard' effect, any 'send to the graveyard' cost.

Comment: The answer is still "No." and companies wanting to make money is a basic reference you yourself declared needing no citation. Accept it and don't be a sore loser!

Comment: So, when you say "make a monster indestructible" per your definition of indestructible, what are the logical boundaries of this? I ask because it sounds like what you're after is more accurately a "non-contestable board state." I.e., not only is "the monster" unable to be removed, but neither are any of the cards protecting it. Do you want the monster to specifically be unaffected when the opponent tries to remove it, or is it acceptable to remove the opponents' options entirely? Are locks acceptable? If not, why are they unacceptable? What are the restrictions, if any, on proposed solutions?

Comment: @squid I think OP is interested in 1 monster card being unaffected/indestructible by all mean, something like tributing Hardened Armed Dragon with his fav monster. Or maybe he want Konami to produce new card like `Holactie` that is unaffected/indestructible/unremovable by all mean but without the winning condition. LOL. Not bad for Konami to trick such people to buy such cards LOL

Comment: @squid I came up with one monster, here is its effect: "You must tribute 5 LV12 monsters to summon this card, and cannot be summoned by other ways. Cards and effects cannot be activated and all cards and effects are negated except this one. Card(s) cannot be set. Monster(s) cannot be summoned. You take no battle damage involving this card." ATK Infinity DEF Infinity / Attr Divine / Type God / LV12`, monster name "Vortex" LOL :D

Comment: @evilReiko I think that's what he wants too, but semantically that's equivalent to an unbreakable lock, so I'd like to have his word on what specifically he views as the separation between what he wants and what has been proposed. Also, that joke monster can still have its summon negated. :P

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you describe, the card that comes to mind that better fits your needs is [Safe Zone](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Safe_Zone):

> Activate this card by targeting 1 face-up Attack Position monster on the field; *that face-up monster cannot be targeted or destroyed by your opponent's card effects, or be destroyed by battle.* It cannot attack your opponent directly. When this card leaves the field, destroy that monster. When that monster leaves the field, destroy this card.

<sub>*emphasis mine*</sub>

Of course, every card has it's trade-offs, and this one's are that you can't attack directly. Also, if Safe Zone is removed that monster is also removed (however, if you are talking about Divine Dragon Knight Felgrand, he can save himself from this destruction with his own effect).

Now, it seems that you have to protect your Safe Zone from being destroyed. One card that can do that is [Imperial Custom](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_Custom):

> Face-up Continuous Trap Cards cannot be destroyed, except "Imperial Custom". You can control only 1 "Imperial Custom".

---

Another way you can make a monster card impervious to any other card is with the effect of [Number 81: Superdreadnought Rail Cannon Super Dora](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Number_81:_Superdreadnought_Rail_Cannon_Super_Dora):

> Once per turn, during either player's turn: You can detach 1 Xyz Material from this card, then target 1 face-up monster on the field; that target is *unaffected by card effects, except for its own effects*, until the end of this turn.

This will prevent basically any target, effect destruction, change of control, or other effects that do not target. Of course, if your opponent summons more muscle than your card's it can still go down by battle. I suppose that combining Safe Zone with Number 81's effect would **really** make it hard to touch.

Other, option you got similar to Number 81 is [Divine Dragon Knight Felgrand](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Divine_Dragon_Knight_Felgrand), which does basically the same plus negating that monster's effect (which could come handy in other scenarios):

> Once per turn, during either player's turn: You can detach 1 Xyz Material from this card, then target 1 face-up monster on the field; this turn, its effects are negated, but it is unaffected by other card effects.

Comment: If I come up with other means I'll update my answer

Comment: That does not make it indestructible, but delays its demise. Maybe a way to make Safe Zone indestructible

Comment: Cards like Heavy storm would destroy Imperial Custom and Safe Zone at the same time, or am I wrong?

Comment: @VortexYT indeed, as you can see the game is smart enough for this to happen to be difficult, so those cards don't become broken.

Comment: @SK19 Heavy Storm is forbidden from play, and I doubt it's coming back. Even though, if it were unrestricted, as the destruction is simultaneously, then safe zone would not be destroyed because at that time of resolution Imperial Custom still protects it.

Comment: @VortexYT I would even say there is no indestructible combo or lock, everything can be countered somehow

Answer (score 0):

**Obviously, that's not possible.**

This is a *game* where each player *challenges* the other. *Challenging*, as a player can narrow down the options of the other player, or can also do a lockdown (where cards are protecting each other in a loop behavior), but not as complete lockdown (that's what you're asking for).

You can do very tight lockdown, where it's almost very difficult to break. Such examples I can think of right now:

[Dark Magician Knight Dragon](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Magician_the_Dragon_Knight) + [Eternal Soul](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Eternal_Soul)

[White Dragon Ninja](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/White_Dragon_Ninja) + [Safe Zone](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Safe_Zone) or [Dimension Guardian](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Dimension_Guardian) (also you can add 3rd card [March of the Monarchs](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/March_of_the_Monarchs) to strengthen the lockdown)

[The Wicked Dreadroot](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/The_Wicked_Dreadroot) + [The Monarachs Awaken](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/The_Monarchs_Awaken)

[Obelisk the Tormentor](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Obelisk_the_Tormentor) + [Hardened Armed Dragon](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Hardened_Armed_Dragon)

**EDIT:**

Here's one more lockdown that I think is indestructible:

[Jinzo](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Jinzo)

[Horus the Black Flame Dragon LV8](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Horus_the_Black_Flame_Dragon_LV8)

[Vanity's Fiend](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Vanity%27s_Fiend)

[Slifer the Sky Dragon](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Slifer_the_Sky_Dragon)

[Black Luster Solider - Envoy of the Beginning](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Black_Luster_Soldier_-_Envoy_of_the_Beginning)

[March of the Monarchs](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/March_of_the_Monarchs)

[Light of Intervention](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Light_of_Intervention)

[Amplifier](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Amplifier) (for Jinzo)

[Mask of Restrict](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Mask_of_Restrict) (to disallow opponent from using Lava Golem and alike monsters)

[Finite Cards](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Finite_Cards) (so opponent cannot win with Exodia)

You can also replace Slifer & Black Luster Solider with [Majesty's fiend](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Majesty%27s_Fiend), and replace Horus with [Spell Canceller](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Spell_Canceller), but you will not be able to include the 3 spell cards.

So you will need on your field 5 monsters + 3 spells + 2 traps (which is most likely impossible to get all these 10 cards on the field). The only way I can think of to break this lockdown is that you ran out of cards to withdraw OR your opponent has already powerful monster(s) on the field before you complete the lockdown.

I wouldn't say it's completely unbreakable, but it's almost unbreakable.

Comment: "Obviously that's not possible" isn't very constructive is it? Do you have any solid evidence, such as a list of the myriad of possible combinations?

Comment: @VortexYT edited my answer, added 1 more lockdown. See if it's breakable.

Comment: *Obviously that's not possible* is a very bold statement, with no evidence whatsoever to say so.

Comment: @VortexYT I'll not claim I know all cards & all rules but I played this game for years and I know it's never going to be possible, and it's true, until someone proves it's otherwise possible.

Comment: @VortexYT btw, this [card](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Stand-Off) might catch your interest, it sounds like it's unbreakable, but it's actually not so hard to break through it

Comment: Then that definitely isn't solid evidence is it?  At Stack Exchange, posts like this are based on evidence, and you haven't even answered my question.

Comment: If anyone is interested in how to break the lockdowns (I think): use any spell that discards for cost to discard Neo-Spacian Grand Mole. Normal Summon Phantom of Chaos (Slifer does not destroy it; its attack is already 0). Banish Grand Mole and attack Horus, return both to hand. Cosmic Cyclone to remove March of the Monarchs, then Raigeki to wipe the monsters away. For the second version, if they have Spell Canceller, it means Jinzo is also negating Mask of Restrict; you can use Winged Dragon of Ra - Sphere Mode to Tribute Spell Canceler, Vanity's and Majesty's, then Lava Golem it and Jinzo.

Comment: Actually, whoops; Amplifier isn't negated by Spell Canceler. Instead, you'll have to Normal Summon Mechanicalchaser, run over Spell Canceler, MST to destroy March of the Monarchs (if it's included), and then Raigeki.

Comment: It's no use trying to argue with Vortex. I tried it over a year ago and apparently they haven't changed. Nice list though :)

Comment: I am glad that you know

Answer (score 0):

## Sort of!

I hope your best card is [Psi-Blocker](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Psi-Blocker), because boy-oh-boy have we got some spicy memes for this one!

Unfortunately, the combo I'm going to highlight here does require the use of several cards that are banned from competitive play. However, if performed, the player would be utterly untouchable.

Back in 2014, a [combo](https://ygorganization.com/infernity-loop-satisfaction-version/) was found which, at the time, would take ***140 days*** to complete... but would literally render every card in the game unusable until the player's next turn by repeatedly summoning and using the effect of Psi-Blocker until every card in the game (not including those required for the loop, of course) was declared. Now, let me reiterate... *at the time* this would take 140 days to complete. The combo is one of my favorites in card games, because over time, more cards are released - meaning that over time, this combo will take even longer.

The jist of the loop involves using the infernities, lavalval chain, hundred-eyes dragon, and a whole host of other infamous looping staples to summon Phantom of Chaos, banish Psi-Blocker, use its effect, summon Leviair the Sea Dragon, summon back Psi-Blocker, use its effect again, do some work to summon Dewloren, return your whole field to hand and do it all again.

## More Along the Lines of What You Asked For:

A scenario where a card cannot be removed or countered by any means is difficult to imagine.. but I believe I have one.

**EDIT:** Updated after [evilReiko](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/27470/evilreiko) pointed out a break. I believe it's now unbreakable, but please feel free to stress test it.

With [Majesty's Fiend](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Majesty%27s_Fiend),

[Denko Sekka](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Denko_Sekka)

[Dark Simorgh](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Simorgh),

[Jinzo](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Jinzo),

[Amplifier](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Amplifier),

[Anti-Spell Fragrance](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Anti-Spell_Fragrance),

[Imperial Iron Wall](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Imperial_Iron_Wall),

and [Mask of Restrict](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Mask_of_Restrict)

already in play, summon [The Last Warrior from Another Planet](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/The_Last_Warrior_from_Another_Planet).

With this field,

- Your opponent cannot summon Monsters by any means (Last Warrior)
- Your opponent cannot Set or activate any Spell/Trap cards, nor Set any Monster cards (Dark Simorgh + Anti-Spell Fragrance)
- Your opponent cannot activate any of their Spell/Trap cards that are already Set (Denko Sekka)
- Your opponent cannot activate Trap Cards like [Infinite Impermanence](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Infinite_Impermanence), which activate directly from the hand (Jinzo)
- Your opponent cannot activate any card effect in their GY by banishing the card (Imperial Iron Wall)
- Your opponent cannot activate monster effects (Majesty's Fiend)

It is not possible for your opponent to take any action with the given board state, so none of your cards can be removed by any means.

I am aware that some might not consider this "making a monster indestructible." I am working on finding some set of cards that cannot be removed *even while* the opponent is able to do things, and will update this answer if I find one, but such a combination is extraordinarily difficult (if not outright impossible) to find.

Comment: The moment you summon The Last Warrior from Another Planet you have to destroy all your other monsters, so you have to summon it first, *if any*, and then try to build up this lock

Comment: @DarkCygnus Since you have Majesty's Fiend out, Last Warrior's effect to destroy your monsters won't activate.

Comment: and as it was in the field before the last warrior nor will the last warrior's continuous ability have effect right? The same thing would happen if it were on the field before Simorgh

Comment: @DarkCygnus That's not correct. Majesty's Fiend prevents the activation of monster effects. It does not negate continuous monster effects.

Comment: I see, I suspected that... the key is the "activated" word, contrary to, say, Skill Drain which gets rid of all effects.

Comment: That's pretty good combo. But you missed something.. How will you be able to summon your monsters if you have The Last Warrior from Another Planet (TLWFAP)? If you summon TLWFAP last then all your monsters will be destroyed, if you summon it first then you will not be able to summon your other monsters.

Comment: @evilReiko See my comment above; TLWFAP will not destroy the monsters due to Majesty's Fiend.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think Lava Golem/Santa Claws/Kaiju/etc can be used. Also, I have seen trap cards that can be activated directly from hand (can't remember which cards). Tough lockdown. Anyway, your answer is invalid according to OP, which he wants a-game-breaker card/combo that is 100% indestructible. We will have to wait for Konami to submit an answer.

Comment: @evilReiko Updated, do feel free to stress test it further if you want.

Comment: @squid That's really epic lockdown! Loophole: opponent may draw all 5 Exodia cards

Comment: @evilReiko I saw Finite Cards in a lock below; I don't agree with its inclusion because the question isn't asking for a lock that the opponent can't win in, it's asking for a situation in which the opponent can't remove anything from your field by any means. On the bright side, even if OP decides Exodia is a loophole after all, Mask of Restrict can be replaced with Fog King so that Finite Cards can be included :D

Comment: Really interesting answer :) although I don't see how it addresses the question asked (how to make monster indestructible).

Comment: @DarkCygnus I agree, which is why I'm still looking through combinations like I mention in my last paragraph. Evidently OP will not be satisfied with a "no" unless every card in the game is checked, so... this is about as close as he can get to a yes. Although, his definition of "indestructible" would suggest that this answer is valid, so I'm not clear on what exactly is keeping it from being accepted.

Comment: If "no" is the answer and you phrase it in a valid way (without having to look throughout all combos), then that would be a valid answer IMHO

Answer (score -1):

I know that this doesn't work for all scenarios but if you are running a dragon deck then it can be quite helpful.
The thing that I would try if the card in question is something like 5-headed dragon or cyber end dragon then you could equip it with a dragon shield which will prevent it from being destroyed by battle or card effect, but neither player takes battle damage when it is involved.
I mentioned cyber end dragon earlier and here is why: You can fusion summon Cyber End Dragon using power bond and then increasing its ATK with 1-3 copies of limiter removal or some equip spells, which will then give you a really high ATK monster which can prevent battle destruction and you could use Damage Vaccine Omega Max to prevent the damage from Power Bond. You could also use Safe Zone to prevent effect destruction but you won't be able to direct attack. If you then wanted to win in that turn you could just attack one of their monsters and you would usually win, but if they have monsters that were say... equipped with Dragon Shield, you could then Tribute those monsters to summon Lava Golem to their field and attack it for game.
I hope that I answered your question decently well and maybe have provided some ideas on how to take an indestructible monster a little bit farther.

Answer (score -1):

I am a professional deck builder and this combo is one of the first competitive combo's I ever used which I came up with myself. Also sorry if this is a tad bit of an old combo but non the less it is powerful... If your monster is "The Last Warrior from Another Planet", you can use "Mystical Beast of Serket" with "Temple of The Kings" to bring him out, affect him with "DNA Surgery" (on turn 1 due to temple of the kings) and use "Secret Village of the Spellcasters" to lock your opponent out of all spells and summons, if you activate 2 Temple of the kings you can also prevent your opponent from using traps by Using allure of darkness to send jinzo to the grave, then reviving him with monster reborn and using amplifier with dimension guardian to make him immune to any type of destruction, this will lock your opponent out of summons (due to last warrior), spells (due to DNA Surgery and Secret Village of the Spellcasters), and traps (due to Amplifier and dimension guardian equipped Jinzo), however this setup is pretty rude (by locking your opponent out of absolutely everything), and requires your  entire deck to be sintered around it. for a more consistent, modern setup, I recommend using a spell heavy setup including a small numeron package with a playset of "Sylvan Princessprite", a very tiny spellbook package (maybe 1 spellbook magician, 2 spellbook of knowledge and 2 spellbook of secrets just for the draw power) XYZ gift and cards like allure of darkness (cards that you can meet the requirements of easily and have great draw power) would be your best friend. sorry if this was drawn out but I remade this deck and 2 out of 3 times I use it I get a final board of the last warrior from another planet, DNA surgery, secret village of the spellcasters, and a jinzo affected by amplifier and dimension guardian by turn 2.

Comment: This answer has a lot of information in it, but it's hard to read as a wall of text. Perhaps some formatting and fewer parentheticals would help make it more readable. It also could use a top-level summary. Consider making an [edit].

Comment: This can be broken by Effect Veiler + Raigeki Break + Farfa, Malebranche of the Burning Abyss. You say "Allure of Darkness to send Jinzo to the grave," but Allure of Darkness banishes the card rather than sends it to grave. You would need additional cards to prevent its banishing, so that Allure would force you to discard your hand instead. Also, per the most recent [errata](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Card_Errata:Temple_of_the_Kings) of Temple of the Kings, you wouldn't be able to use a second trap via its effect in the same turn.